# Thread over uneven (ragged) expressions with full functionality?

Tags: expression-manipulation

There are a number of questions on this site about "threading" including several relating to uneven (ragged) lists.  However, none that I could find deal with the full functionality of `Thread` but instead things like `MapThread`, or the ragged transpose of `Flatten[expr, {2}]`.

`Thread` operates:

- Inside held expressions without errant evaluation
- On arbitrary heads as specified with the second parameter
- By distributing singlets across all subexpressions
- On only the first *n* arguments (subexpressions) if given as third parameter

For example:

```
expr = Hold[qq[2 + 2, 1/0, 8/4], qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]];

Thread[expr, qq]

Thread[expr, qq, 1]
```

> ```
> qq[Hold[2 + 2, 1, Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[1/0, 2, Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[8/4, 3, Sqrt[2 + 2]]]
>
> qq[Hold[2 + 2, qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[1/0, qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]], 
>    Hold[8/4, qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]]]
> ```

All of this breaks if we change `qq[1, 2, 3]` to `qq[1, 2]`.

What is the most efficient way to extend `Thread` to ragged subexpressions?

Answer (score 6):

This is my take on the pad, thread normally, then remove padding approach.

```
fred[expr_, head_: List, seq_: All] := 
 Module[{myhold, maxlength, dummy, paddedexpr}, 
  SetAttributes[myhold, HoldAllComplete];
  maxlength = Max@Cases[expr, head[args___] :> Length@Hold@args, {1}];
  paddedexpr = Replace[expr, head[args___] :>
     RuleCondition@PadRight[myhold@args, maxlength, dummy], {1}];
  DeleteCases[Thread[paddedexpr, myhold, seq], dummy, -1] /. myhold -> head]
```

Comment: Much more polished :) I didn't know `Pad..` worked on arbitrary heads. Sweet.

Comment: +1, I would have done something quite similar. I think the Replace level better be {1} in case the whole expression is wrapped in head.

Comment: Also, there's the small issue of definitions that didn't match now matching with the padded dummy arguments. Perhaps keeping the `myhold` and some other one for the head of heads, and replacing them back after the threading? Not sure if I am thinking straight, and I don't have MMA to try stuff

Comment: @Rojo, thanks - good points.

Answer (score 5):

// timidly raises hand

Maybe this approach?

```
ClearAll[Thread2];
SetAttributes[Thread2, HoldAllComplete];
Thread2[expr_, etc___] :=
  DeleteCases[
   Thread[
    With[
     {max = Length /@ {expr} // Max},
     Quiet[
      Replace[
       expr,
       h_[c___] /; 1 < Length@{c} < max :> 
         RuleCondition[
           h[c,
             Sequence @@ ConstantArray[EatMe, max - Length@{c}]]],
       {1}]]], etc], 
   EatMe, 3];

expr = Hold[qq[2 + 2, 1/0, 8/4], qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]];    
Thread2[expr, qq]
Thread2[expr, qq, 1]
```

> ```
> qq[Hold[2 + 2, 1, Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[1/0, 2, Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[8/4, 3, Sqrt[2 + 2]]]
>
> qq[Hold[2 + 2, qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[1/0, qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]],  Hold[8/4, qq[1, 2, 3], Sqrt[2 + 2]]]
> ```

```
expr2 = Hold[qq[2 + 2, 1/0, 8/4], qq[1, 2], Sqrt[2 + 2]];
Thread2[expr2, qq]
Thread2[expr2, qq, 1]
```

> ```
> qq[Hold[2 + 2, 1, Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[1/0, 2, Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[8/4, Sqrt[2 + 2]]]
>
> qq[Hold[2 + 2, qq[1, 2], Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[1/0, qq[1, 2], Sqrt[2 + 2]], Hold[8/4, qq[1, 2], Sqrt[2 + 2]]]
> ```

Comment: There is no need to be timid.  Thanks for answering.  I had my own ideas for implementing this but I wasn't feeling very imaginative so I wanted to see how others would do it.

Comment: `Thread2[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}]` gives a Thread::tdlen error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking to use Thread  on ragged subexpressions. I will give my solution on  ragged list:

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, f, r, t}, {t, y, k}};
length = Length[#] & /@ list;
max = Max@length;
list2 = Join[#, ConstantArray[0, max - Length[#]]] & /@ list;
list3 = Thread[List @@ list2];
list4 = DeleteCases[list3, _ 0, \[Infinity]];
f @@@ list4

(*    {f[a, c, t], f[b, f, y], f[r, k], f[t]}*)
```

Comment: Is this intended to be only an illustration?  Will this handle the additional parameters of `Thread`?  I think you would also need to avoid accidentally deleting zeros that were present in the original expression.  By the way, you don't need to write `Length[#] & /@ list` -- `Length` is already a function, so write: `Length /@ list`. :-)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, thank you for your input. regarding deleting zero, this can be changed to be any value that is not showing in the ragged list.